# What security settings in IE prevent running autoit form submit macros?

Tags: amazon-web-services, group-policy, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, autoit

I'm trying to automate logging in to Amazon Web Services with autoit on a fairly hardened windows machine.  I can run a script as admin on the box and it works just fine, but when I go in as a user under the "hardened" rules (hardened by installing Cyberark PSM software).

I had to modify the Group Policy just to allow javascript to not redirect to the default AWS landing page.  My autoit script is putting the Username and Password in, but it's not successfully clicking the Sign In link under this user (although the return value from calling click in the autoit script says it worked). This autoit script works on my PC and it works on that Server if I'm logged in as administrator, just not as the locked down user.

```
$uname=$TargetUsername
$pwd=$TargetPassword
_IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery1, $uname)
_IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery2, $pwd)

_IEAction ($oButton, "click")

_IELoadWait($oIE,0)
```

I've tried using formSubmit too and that had the same results. I have also tried to call the oauth javascript method directly, but I'm not sure what that is and the things I tried with autoit have not worked.